# ERROR: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1

Tags: pytorch, index-error

The following code gave the error 'too many indices for tensor dimension 1, with m, M, g, L all being parameters:

```
  f = [ x[r][1], ((0.5*g*m*np.sin(2*x[r][2]))-(l*m*((x[r][3])**2)*np.sin(x[r][2])))/((m*(np.sin(x[r][2])**2))+M), 
             x[r][3], ((g*(M+m)*np.sin(x[r][2]))-(l*m*((x[r][3])**2)*np.sin(x[r][2])*np.cos(x[r][2])))/(l*((m*(np.sin(x[r][2])**2))+M))]
        y.append(f)                                                                                   
    y = torch.tensor(y)

---> 15     y[:,1] = y[:,1] + ((u[:,1])/((m*((np.sin(x[r][2]))**2))+M))
     16     y[:,3] = y[:,3] + ((u[:,3]*np.cos(x[r][2]))/(l*((m*((np.sin(x[r][2]))**2))+M)))
     17     return 

IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1.
```

Does anyone know what went wrong in writing this code?

Comment: You should give a minimally reproductible example. Write example inputs in your question (as well as values for r, m, ...). You should also break down your code into simpler statements, because here it is unreadable and hard to debug because so many thing is done in one line.

Comment: You should also write in the question the function shown in the error.